# Type Search has no compatible call signatures Angular 5+

Tags: angular, typescript

An `addItem` function which I got from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5ew8f?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) is giving me this error message:

> Error TS2349  (TS) Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call
>   signature. Type 'Search' has no compatible call signatures.

Interface:

```
export interface Search {
    name: String;
    type: String;
    inputValue: String;
}
```

Declerations:

```
array : Search[];
searches: Search[];
```

TypeScript:

```
addItems(startIndex, endIndex, _method) {
    let movieIndex = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sum; ++i) {
      movieIndex++;
      if (movieIndex >= this.searches.length) movieIndex = 0;
      this.array[_method](this.searches[movieIndex]);
    }
}
```

Invokation:

`this.addItems(startIndex, endIndex, 'push');`

DataSource(from node server):

```
fetchSearches() {
this.searchService.getSearches()
  .subscribe((data: Search[]) => {
    this.searches = data
    this.searches.forEach(search => {
      search.inputValue = search.name;
    })
    console.log('Data requested...')   
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement

```
this.array[_method](this.searches[movieIndex]);
```

means that you try to get the `_method`-th item of `this.array` and want to invoke it (`()` this is call of the function) passing parameter `this.searches[movieIndex]`, but your array contains elements of type `Search` which is not invokable

```
this.array[_method] ( this.searches[movieIndex] );
                    ^ ^------ parameter ------^ ^
                    ^ ------ function call -----^
```

Comment: When I use an array with the json data it work but when I try with the Interface I get that error message. Is it possible to get the same outcome with the interface or do I have to use an array?

Comment: What do you have in your array when you use json data ?

Comment: I use the example json in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5ew8f?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) `app.component.ts` movies array.

Comment: In that example it is accessing not the items but function of the `Array` such as `push` or `pop`. Maybe you are passing not a function key ?

Comment: yes, `this.addItems(startIndex, endIndex, 'push');` and `this.addItems(startIndex, endIndex, 'unshift');`

Comment: Check your `_method` which you pass into it. There may be a typo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178629/discussion-between-decoder94-and-suren-srapyan).

Comment: I changed my declerations: to `array =[]` and `searches :Search[]=[]`;